# Suppose $\alpha , \beta $ and $\gamma$ are functions if $\alpha\circ\gamma = \beta\circ\gamma$ and $\gamma$ is bijective, prove that $\alpha = \beta$

Tags: proof-verification

So what I did was say that for every $x$ in $\gamma$ we have $\alpha(\gamma(x))=\beta(\gamma(x))$ and since $\gamma$ is bijective $x$ gets mapped to only one element of the range and will call this $y$. Now we have $\alpha(y)=\beta(y)$ and then i basically said since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both functions and there range is equal the source from the domain can't be different by the definition of a function. But after thinking for awhile I decided that I am probably wrong. The hint i received was to apply $\gamma^{-1}$. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(\alpha\circ\gamma)\circ\gamma^{-1}=(\beta\circ\gamma)\circ\gamma^{-1}$

Comment: That's what the hint was saying. If I do that I would write it like this $\alpha(\gamma(\gamma^{-1})) = \beta(\gamma(\gamma^{-1}))$ and then would the $\gamma$'s just cancel out? leaving $\alpha=\beta$?

Comment: yes, because $\gamma$ is bijective and composition of functions is associative

Comment: for some reason i wasn't thinking about the composition of functions being associative. Thank you